# is it possible to make an array with multiple types of data?

Tags: arrays, c, types

i'm new to coding and currently doing it in c,
i have to write a program that reads N elements given by the user and saves them in a array. the program has to generate a new array where:

1. each repeated number in the first array has to appear only once in the second array
2. each 0 on the first array doesn't have to appear in the second array

it has to work with ints, chars and floats; and it has to have two versions a random elements one and a user given one.

this is what i have for now, it works with ints and chars but not floats

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main()
{
    // asks input for array size
    int maxnum;
    printf("How long will the array be? ");
    scanf("%d", &maxnum);
    fflush(stdin);

    char array[maxnum];
    char answer;

    do
    {
        // asks if user wants to input elements or prefers random
        printf("Would you like to input characters (i) or generate random ones (r)?: ");
        scanf("%c", &answer);
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    while(answer != 'i' && answer != 'r');

    if(answer == 'i')
    {
      // asks input for elements of the array
        printf("Enter %d characters for the array: ", maxnum);
        for(int i = 0; i < maxnum; i++)
        {
            scanf("%30s", &array[i]);
        }
    }
    else if(answer == 'r')
    {
        srand(time(0));
        printf("Characters for the array: ", maxnum);
        for(int i = 0; i < maxnum; i++)
        {
            // generates a random number as the element of the array
            array[i] = (rand() % (126 - 33 + 1)) + 33;
            printf("%c ", array[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    // loop that goes on for the length of the array
    for(int i = 0; i < maxnum; i++)
    {
        // if the element is a 0, it is deleted from the array
        if(array[i] == '0')
        {
            for(int k = i; k < maxnum; k++)
            {
                array[k] = array[k + 1];
            }
            // the length of the array is shortened by one
            maxnum--;
        }

        // checks the next element
        for(int j = i + 1; j < maxnum;)
        {
            // if the next element is the same, it is deleted
            if(array[i] == array[j])
            {
                for(int k = j; k < maxnum; k++)
                {
                    array[k] = array[k + 1];
                }
                maxnum--;
            }
            else
            {
                j++;
            }
        }
    }

    // prints final array
    printf("Final array: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < maxnum; i++)
    {
        printf("%c ", array[i]);
    }


    printf("\n\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What you have doesn't actually work with `int`s, try doing an `int` > 256 and see what happens.

Comment: No it is not possible to have an array of multiple types in C. Please edit your post to provide: expected and current behavior, inputs / outputs, concrete question requiring help.

Answer (score 4):

C 2018 6.2.5 20 says:

> … An *array type* describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects with a particular member object type, called the *element type*.

So every element in an array must have the same type.

To record different types within an array, you can use structures and unions.

An example of a structure declaration is:

```
struct CIF
{
    char  c;
    int   i;
    float f;
};
```

This creates a type named `struct CIF`. It holds a `char`, and `int`, **and** a `float`. You can create an instance of such a structure with `struct CIF x;`. Then you can access members of the structure using `.name` to access the member with name `name`:

```
struct CIF x;
x.c = 'A';
x.i = 7;
x.f = 11.25;
```

An example of a union declaration is:

```
union CIF
{
    char  c;
    int   i;
    float f;
};
```

This creates a type named `union CIF`. It holds a `char`, and `int`, **or** a `float`. The same memory is used for each member of the union, so writing one overwrites the others. Normally, you use only one member a time:

```
union CIF x;
x.c = 'A';
printf("The char is %c.\n", x.c);
x.i = 7;
printf("The int is %d.\n", x.i);
x.f = 11.25;
printf("The float is %g.\n", x.f);
```

You can use a combination of a structure and a union to hold one of various types as well as a code indicating which type is currently in the union:

```
struct CIF;
{
    char type;
    union
    {
        char  c;
        int   i;
        float f;
    } u;
};
```

Now we can use the `type` member of the structure to remember which type we have in the union member. The union member is named `u`. We will use the characters `'c'`, `'i'`, and `'f'` for codes, but we could make up any code we like:

```
struct CIF x;
x.type = 'i';
x.u.f  = 11.25;
switch (x.type)
{
    case 'c':
        printf("x contains a character, %c.\n", x.u.c);
        break;
    case 'i':
        printf("x contains an int, %d.\n", x.u.i);
        break;
    case 'f':
        printf("x contains a float, %g.\n", x.u.f);
        break;
    default:
        printf("x contains an invalid type code.\n");
        break;
}
```

Then we can create an array of these structures:

```
struct CIF x[10];
x[3].type = 'i';
x[3].u.f  = 11.25;
switch (x[3].type)
{
    case 'c':
        printf("x[3] contains a character, %c.\n", x[3].u.c);
        break;
    case 'i':
        printf("x[3] contains an int, %d.\n", x[3].u.i);
        break;
    case 'f':
        printf("x[3] contains a float, %g.\n", x[3].u.f);
        break;
    default:
        printf("x[3] contains an invalid type code.\n");
        break;
}
```

Two points for further consideration:

- Enumerations declared with `enum` may be used for codes.
- The member name `u` may be left out of the `union` inside the structure. This creates an anonymous union. Its members become “direct” members of the structure, so they may be accessed with `x.c`, `x.i.`, and `x.f` instead of `x.u.c`, `x.u.i`, and `x.u.f`.

Comment: In this particular case, it might be easier to just save everything in the array as a string, since it doesn't look like OP needs to really use the elements for much.